# How can I handle non-English keycodes?

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'm creating hangman game with JavaScript. Keycode is the number equivalent of letters in the console log.

If I want to use just [a-z] alphabet keys I have to set as between 65 and 90.

But I also have non-English letters.

Keycodes for non-English letters are = [186, 191, 219, 220,221]. How can I include these letters?

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    // console.log(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <=90) {
        const letter = e.key;
        console.log(e.keyCode)

        if (selectedWord.includes(letter)) {
            if(!correctLetters.includes(letter)) {
                correctLetters.push(letter);
                displayWord();
            } else {
                showNotification();
            }
        } else {
            if(!wrongLetters.includes(letter)) {
                wrongLetters.push(letter);

                updateWrongLettersEl();
            } else {
                showNotification();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: Yusuf - Glad you got a solution. Whomever's answer helped you out, please accept their answer, which you can do by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.indexOf(value)`, which will search the array for the value and return the position of the found value. If it doesn't find the value, you'll get `-1`.

```
// set up an array of the keys
var nonEnglishKeys = [186, 191, 219,220,221];

// then in your if statement, check for indexOf()
// if it doesn't equal -1, that means it's one of your keys
if((e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <=90) || nonEnglishKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
...
```